# document.ready is to slow, it takes like 2min to load

Tags: jquery

I have some problem using document.ready, it slows down the loading time with sometimes up to two minutes.

I saw this link : http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

So my question is, how can I use that approach instead of document.ready ?

here's my document.ready function inside custom.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setBudgetPeriodReadOnly();
  adjustTablePerBudgetNiva(budgetNiva);
  disableDeletedAccounts();
  allowedKeyCodes();
  showHideZeroRowsEvent();
  removeZeroOnClick();
  bindMouseOverOutEvent();
  bindTableRowEvents();
  returnAsTabEvent();
  budgetNivaChangedEvent();
```

});

as you see it contains some functions, and those functions using child functions and so on.

here's a sample of a function using live

```
function bindMouseOverOutEvent() {    
$('#budgetTable tr').live({
    mouseover: function () {
        $(this).find('td:eq(6)')
               .removeClass('budgetBelopp')
               .end().toggleClass('budgetTable-hover');
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        $(this).find('td:eq(6)')
               .addClass('budgetBelopp')
               .end().toggleClass('budgetTable-hover');

    }
});
```

}

but its not working because its wrapped in a function, and I want them to be wrapped so I see on the function name what the function is doing.

I'm also new to jQuery.

Comment: 2 minutes? Sounds like you've got something blocking execution. Are you perhaps loading synchronously in one of those functions?

Comment: After converting the functions to use `.live()`, did you remove the `$(document).ready()` and instead just call the functions immediately?

Comment: how can I use a event that is wrapped in a function like the one above, without using document.ready ? When i put it in a namned function it doesn't get triggered if it havent been loaded from within document.ready

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: I got like 500 textboxes generated dynamically, so I need to speed up the script.

Comment: @n3tx Check this [benchmark](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/ccm3z/). It's adding 10000 elements, and it takes only ~170ms when concatenating the html. So 500 shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: ok, maybe it's the server code that is lacking. Anyway, still need to fix the problem with document.ready. I removed all functions from document.ready that have an event like click, keydown and so on, and added the live event instead to those. But now they dont get triggered because they are wrapped in a namned function. How can I trigger them without removing the wrapping ?

Comment: Stop worrying about `$(document).ready`. The functions have got to be run in response to some event or other and `$(document).ready` is the earliest event that will do the job. Start running some diagnostics - send some timing messages to the log to see which function(s) are taking longer than they should.

Comment: I would be inclined to ignore every single word of advice offered in the referenced article. No only is `.live()` now deprecated in favour of `.on()`, but it should also not no used as a general panacea for improving page responsiveness. If anything, it will have the opposite effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your script file at the haad like `<script async defer src="..."></script>`

Answer (score -2):

put the javascript at the bottom of the website

Comment: -1. This presents the same potential issues as waiting for the DOM to be ready

Comment: -1 As above. Also, this is would have been more fitting in the comments.